# three.js - Creating mesh from .obj file using geometry.vertices and geometry.faces

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a mesh from an .obj file. I am doing this rather than using the obj loader because I meed to morph the shape using different sliders, select specific faces/vertices and draw a path between vertices.

I am currently getting errors when I try to render the scene and it seems to be something to do with the faces from the obj file. When I manually enter the faces I can create a triangle no problem.

Here is my code

```
   var camera, scene, renderer,
    geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/img/originalMeanModel.obj', false);
    xhr.send(null);
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var lines = text.split("\n");
    for (i=0; i<19343; i++){
      lines[i] = lines[i].split(" ");
    }

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 1, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.z = 20;
    scene.add( camera );

    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry()

  /* 
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -0.01,  0.01, 0 ) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( -0.01, -0.01, 0 ) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0.01, -0.01, 0 ) );
  */
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );



    for(i=0; i<6449; i++){
      geometry.vertices.push( 
             new THREE.Vector3( 
              parseFloat(lines[i][1]),   
              parseFloat(lines[i][2]), 
              parseFloat(lines[i][3])) );
    }

    /*
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 600, 1, 3000 ) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 3000, 6400, 70 ) );
    */


    for(i=6449; i<19343; i++){
      geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( parseInt(lines[i][1]), parseInt(lines[i][2]), parseInt(lines[i][3]) ) );
    }

    console.log(geometry.faces);
    console.log(geometry.vertices);


    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: false } );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    scene.add( mesh );

    renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
}

function animate() {
    // note: three.js includes requestAnimationFrame shim
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
}

function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

When I inspect the console the faces and vertices have been printed out as expected. I also have this error printed out 5700+ times

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined       Three.js:71
projectScene                                                          Three.js:71
render                                                               Three.js:245
render                                                          threeDemo.php:115
animate                                                         threeDemo.php:106
```

threeDemo.php:106 is this line of the animate function

```
render();
```

threeDemo.php:115 is this line of the render function

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

Here is a link the the obj file that I am trying to create a mesh for. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/23384412/originalMeanModel.obj

Is anyone could point me in the right direction it would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using OBJLoader for loading the different frames and using the parsed data for creating the new geometry?

Comment: Hi @mrdoob ! I need to show paths between vertices and click and select/highlight specific vertices. From looking at documentation I could only see a way of doing this by creating a mesh using geometry. If this isn't the case can you point me to some documentation/example? Thanks

Comment: If you use OBJLoader then you have a geometry of it, right? If you have 2 frames, then you use OBJLoader two times and you have 2 geometries, right? Then you can read both geometries and create a third geometry with the lines that would go from the points of the first geometry to the second.

Comment: Thanks @mrdoob ! If that is the case could you take a look at my edited question as to why ray.intersectObjects(scene.children); doesn't work when I create the mesh using the obj loader. Thanks again! :)

Comment: I think it's better if you create a new question for that. I can then post my answer as a proper answer for the original question.

Comment: @mrdoob edit removed and put in new question [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205784/three-js-using-projector-and-ray-to-selected-a-vertex) Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `OBJLoaders` for loading each frame geometry. Then create a third `Geometry` and create the lines using as reference the vertices from the frame geometries.