# Object not loading with JSONLoader in ThreeJS: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I am trying to load an object model using the following code:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('js/spacecraft.js', modelLoadedCallback);

function modelLoadedCallback(geometry) {
   spacecraft = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(geometry.materials));
   spacecraft.position.x = 0;
   spacecraft.position.y = 0;
   spacecraft.position.z = 0;
   mesh.add(spacecraft);
   scene.add( mesh );
}
```

Nonetheless, in every renderer.render(..) call I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined
```

I have no idea about the error because both the mesh and spacecraft objects seem to be properly loaded when inspecting in the console.

Am I missing something with the JSONLoader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what was happening: the model in `spacecraft.js` had an empty `materials` array for some reason... I need to find out the cause because I used NodeJS three-obj library for converting .obj to .JSON

Answer (score 1):

Could you give the line number/file of that error? It could be inside of spacecraft, or at some other line in your code?

look in js/spacecraft.js and find what is trying to use .visible, e.g. `myObj.visible` A quick-fix is to surround this with `if(myObj != undefined){ ... };` But a more general fix would be to find out why myObj.visible is undefined in the first place.

Comment: Hi! It's a nice idea, I tried it before, but somehow the error keeps showing up. The error occurs in the renderer.render(..) call, inside the ThreeJS script file.

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11192283/three-js-creating-mesh-from-obj-file-using-geometry-vertices-and-geometry-fac